# Search json value in whereIn in laravel?

Tags: json, laravel

```
$exams=[{"id":1}];

$toReturn['exams'] =exams_list::whereIn('examClasses',$exams)->get()->toArray();
```

How to do this?

Comment: `$exams=[{"id":1}];` is the wrong way to initialize object. It should be `$exams=["id"=>1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
$exam_id = 1;
$toReturn['exams'] =exams_list::where('examClasses->"$.id"',$exam_id)->get()->toArray();

//As per your question
//$exams=[{"id":1}]; =======> Wrong way
$exams=["id" => 1];
$toReturn['exams'] =exams_list::where('examClasses->"$.id"',$exam["id"])->get()->toArray();
```

See example given below, Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

> - column->path
>
> In MySQL 5.7.9 and later, the -> operator serves as an alias for the JSON_EXTRACT() function when used with two arguments, a column identifier on the left and a JSON path on the right that is evaluated against the JSON document (the column value). You can use such expressions in place of column identifiers wherever they occur in SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you @vaibhavaraj, But this is not working. here, $exam_id=[{"id":1}];

Comment: Thankyou @Vaibhav

Comment: Is `$exams` is dynamic value? if yes then you can do as `$exams = json_decode($exams);`

Comment: Yeah...its a dynamic value. But when i try to use json_decode,showing  500 (Internal Server Error) . Here , the value is returned back to angular js fn, so dd() is also not working.