# How to search from multiple columns in laravel with comma separated values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
id | company_name | country_id | city_id | main_category
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ABC          |   1        |  2      |  1,3,6
 2 | XYZ          |   1        |  2      |  1,8,9
```

I want to search list of companies specific ids from user input with `country_id, city_id, main_category` but i don't know how to find from main category   in laravel in eloquent way

What i tried is

```
  $matchThese = [ 'country_id' => $request->input('country'),
                        'city_id' => $request->input('city'),

                    ];

  $results = Company::where($matchThese)->get();
```

how can i also include main_category for search.

Comment: do you want to match all `main_category`?? Better explain with some sample data.

Comment: What is the type of `main_category`?

Comment: @abdullah, u are walking in wrong way.  this is not relational concept with main_category field. if u want to anything by json datatype so u can follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: This is really a bad design storing multiple values as comma separated string in single column

Comment: yeah i know its bad design but i have to go with it Because i m modifying other developer's code and he's left.
the query i tried is working fine but problem is with `main_category`where values are separated by commas and the values i am getting i have to search from `main_category`

Comment: You should convert `main_category` into json datatype of mysql. then you can search by whereIn clause.  Here is a stackoverflow question. it can help u to get idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641696/search-json-value-in-wherein-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `main_category` is `VARCHAR` or similar, you need to do this:

```
Company::where(function($q) use($categoryId) {
        $q->where('main_category', 'like', '%,' . $categoryId . ',%')
        $q->orWhere('main_category', 'like', $categoryId . ',%')
        $q->orWhere('main_category', 'like', '%,' . $categoryId)
    })
    ->where($matchThese)->get();
```

But a much better way to handle this is to use many to many relationship between `Company` and `Category` models. You need to create a new pivot table `category_company` and use it as described in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: this work but i i want to include country_id, city_id too

Comment: @abdullah these are included. Look at the `->where($matchThese)` part.

Answer (score 2):

You can include multiple `where` methods in the query builder.

```
$results = Company::where('country_id', $request->input('country'))
           ->where('city_id', $request->input('country'))
           ->get();
```

Also, to query any comma separated data, you can use `whereRaw` from query builder and `FIND_IN_SET` from MySQL.

```
$main_category_id = 5;

$results = Company::whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET($main_category_id, main_category) > 0")
           ->get();
```

Comment: how can i combine both the queries and create single query that works from me

Comment: may be this  after first query `$results->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET($main_category_id,main_category) > 0")->get();`

Comment: append `whereRaw` to other `where` clause, as mentioned in above answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by chaining where methods like this
`$results = Company::where('country_id', $request->input('country'))->where('city_id', $request->input('city'))->get();`

Comment: Your code does not at all attempt to answer the question regarding main_category.